Scrollbar in simple HTML appearing
This code below shows a HTML scroll-bar.


<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="oCol1" class="col-sm-12  col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
          <table style="width:100%; border: none">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    Test
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



This is the simplest I can make it - the code is generated. Why am I getting a horizontal scroll bar with this HTML. I can't add a overflow: hide as in other scenarios there will be wide content - this case is not one of them.

Remove style of width:100% from inline styling. Page is already responsive.

And reason why having this in there would cause a scrollbar tho? I'm interested in knowing why this is happening (I should be able to stack 10 divs with width:100% w/o a scrollbar)

Cause of horizontal scrollbar is linked with bootstrap. If you inspect the table and row, you will find --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem; applied to row which is causing the issue if you set it to 0 it will get fixed. Add this .row{--bs-gutter-x: 0 !important;} and it will get fixed.
Below is  working example of same and if I have missed something then do share.
Note: Vertical scrollbar in below runtime is just visible in SO


.row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 0 !important;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0 !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <h2 class="mainDiv">


    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="oCol1" class="col-sm-12  col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
            <table style="width:100%; border: none">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      Test
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </h2>
</body>

</html>



